# Why are chunks/nodes created smaller than the specified chunk_size? LLama index

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, large-language-model, llama, llama-index

Im trying to create storage where every chunk has size 1000 tokens. Also I use retriever for questions so I want to retrieve chunks for my questions like this: 3 questions => 3000 tokens of context (earch node is 1000). But if check the number of tokens of each retrieved node, it's less then 1000 (it can be 70, 150, 200).
My code:

```js
  documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('data').load_data()    
  service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(chunk_size=1000)
  index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context=service_context)
  index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir='./storage')
  
  ai = AIChat(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, console=False, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k")
  
  storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir='./storage')
  index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
  
  query_srt = "What is the main idea of this text?"
  
  retriever = index.as_retriever(similarity_top_k=2)
  
  nodes = retriever.retrieve(query_srt)
```

Every node in "nodes" have less then 1000 tokens (I check it with len(word_tokenize(node.text))). I tried to provide chunk_overlap but it didn't work. How to get nodes with size 1000 from store?